# Laravel 8 - Error Class 'App\Student' not found in StudentController.php

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-8

hopefully someone can enlighten me on this bug. Laravel 8. I am replicating a simple blog from this url: https://www.codewall.co.uk/laravel-crud-demo-with-resource-controller-tutorial/

It seems like sometimes you do these tutorials but laravel 8 is slightly different. What am I missing here? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Getting error when going to /students & a /students/create urls , I am getting different errors for

/students (index) error -
***Error
Class 'App\Student' not found***

It doesn't like the create route either which is weird because I have store method in StudentController.

/students/create (create) error -
***Action StudentController@store not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara-blog2\blog\resources\views\students\create.blade.php)***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Student;

class StudentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $students = Student::all();
        return view('students.index', compact('students','students'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('students.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'age' => 'required|numeric',
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        Student::create($input);

        return redirect()->route('students.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $student = Student::findOrFail($id);
        return view('students.show', compact('student','student'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $student = Student::find($id);
        
        return view('students.edit', compact('student','student'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $student = Student::findOrFail($id);

        $this->validate($request, [
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'age' => 'required|numeric',
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        $student->fill($input)->save();

        return redirect()->route('students.index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $student = Student::findOrFail($id);

        $student->delete();
        
        return redirect()->route('students.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: On laravel 8, it would be `use App\Models\Student;`

Comment: Can you share more details? Did you define that class `App\Student`  anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Laravel 8, all models now are located in `App\Models` directory in `App` directory as previous versions, so you need to update your import statement to be

```
use App\Models\Student;
```

Read more about `Models` new directory in Laravel Release Notes [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#models-directory)

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8, all models now are located in App/Models so use

```
use App\Models\Student;
```

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel 8, all models are now located in the App\Models directory in the App directory as in previous versions, so you need to update your import statement to be

App\Models\Student; instead of App\Student;

Comment: This answer is already available in other answers.